# Optimise pl/sql execution time

Tags: oracle, optimization, plsql

I have a pl/sql procedure (Oracle 11g) that takes a long time to execute
(3h for 195.000 rows).

So the goal is to speed it up.

The code uses `bulk collect` and `for all` supposedly to speed up `dmls`, however there are some computations that are done on bulk collected data. These are done inside a classical `for loop`. And this for loop also accesses some other tables (performs selects) in order to perform computations needed. I think that part is one that slows everything down.

Consider the  code below (it is modified and stripped down version of the real code - just to give you a gist of what is going on):

```
procedure long_runnig_task is 
         TYPE my_record is RECORD(key1  number, key2  number, key3 number , 
         key4 number, p1 number ,p2 number, place_holder1  number, 
         place_holder2  number,place_holder3  number );

         TYPE my_record_table  IS TABLE OF my_record;
         l_data my_record_table;

 cursor c is
          select key1, key2 , key3 ,key4 ,
          (select param from paramtable where param_id=1) p1,
          (select param from paramtable where param_id=2) p2,
          0 place_holder1 ,0 place_holder2, 0 place_holder3 from mytable where myflag=4;
begin
     open c;
        loop
            begin
            fetch c bulk collect into l_data limit 1000;
            savepoint mysp;
            FOR indx IN 1 .. l_data.COUNT
           loop 
              --computations per record 
              select max(amount) into myValue1 from table3 where 
              key1=l_data(indx).kay1 and 
              key2=l_data(indx).kay2 and key3=l_data(indx).kay3 and key4=l_data(indx).kay4;

              select amount into myValue2 from table4 where key1=l_data(indx).kay1 
              and 
              key2=l_data(indx).kay2 and key3=l_data(indx).kay3 and key4=l_data(indx).kay4;

              select amount into myValue3 from table5 where key1=l_data(indx).kay1 
              and 
              key2=l_data(indx).key2 and key3=l_data(indx).key3 and key4=l_data(indx).key4;

              l_data(indx).place_holder1 := myValue1;
              l_data(indx).place_holder2 := someFunction(myValue2,l_data(indx).p1);
              l_data(indx).palce_holder3 := myValue3*l_data(indx).p2;

       end loop;

  forall indx IN 1 .. l_data.COUNT 
     update table6 set v= l_data(indx).place_holder1 where  key1=l_data(indx).key1 
     and 
     key2=l_data(indx).key2 and key3=l_data(indx).key3 and key4=l_data(indx).key4;

  forall indx IN 1 .. l_data.COUNT 
     insert into table7(col1,col2,col3) values (l_data(indx).place_holder3,sysdate,l_data(indx).place_holder2/10); 

 exception when others then
            rollback to mysp;
            raise;
 end; 
exit when c%notfound;
end loop;


exception when others then
     rollback;
    raise; 
    end;
```

Any suggestions on how to optimise the performance of the above are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to profile this SP? What does profiler said about main time consumers?

Comment: Why are you doing lots of individual selects inside the loop, instead of joining to those three tables in your cursor query?

Comment: @AlexPoole You are right! ;-) Thanks for the tip - Did just that and the performance improved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done in two sql statements:

```
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO table6 tgt
    USING (SELECT key1,
                  key2,
                  key3,
                  key4,
                  (SELECT MAX(amount)
                   FROM   table3 t3
                   WHERE  t3.key1 = mt.key1
                   AND    t3.key2 = mt.key2
                   AND    t3.key3 = mt.key3
                   AND    t3.key4 = mt.key4) place_holder1
           FROM   mytable mt
           WHERE  myflag = 4) src
      ON (tgt.key1 = src.key1
         AND tgt.key2 = src.key2
         AND tgt.key3 = src.key3
         AND tgt.key4 = src.key4)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET tgt.v = src.place_holder1;

  INSERT INTO table7
    (col1,
     col2,
     col3)
  SELECT place_holder3 * mt.p2 val3,
         SYSDATE dt,
         somefunction(place_holder2, mt.p1) val2,
  FROM   (SELECT (SELECT param
                  FROM   paramtable
                  WHERE  param_id = 1) p1,
                 (SELECT param
                  FROM   paramtable
                  WHERE  param_id = 2) p2,
                 (SELECT amount
                         FROM   table4
                         WHERE  t4.key1 = mt.key1
                         AND    t4.key2 = mt.key2
                         AND    t4.key3 = mt.key3
                         AND    t4.key4 = mt.key4) place_holder2,
                        (SELECT amount
                         FROM   table5
                         WHERE  t5.key1 = mt.key1
                         AND    t5.key2 = mt.key2
                         AND    t5.key3 = mt.key3
                         AND    t5.key4 = mt.key4)/10 place_holder3
          FROM   mytable mt
          WHERE  myflag = 4);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    RAISE;
END;
/
```

N.B. this does assume that for each key1, key2, key3 and key4 in mytable there is a corresponding row in table3, table4 and table5. By doing scalar subqueries, if there isn't a row present in those tables, null will be returned, rather than an error being generated (no_data_found) in your current code. You'll have to amend the above procedure to generate an error if such a condition occurs.

The way I did this was to take the cursor sql and then add in the subsequent sql statements as scalar subqueries in the cursor's sql.

Then I noticed that the insert and update were using different values (the update used the place_holder1 value, the insert the place_holder2 and place_holder3 values (amended appropriately). Then it was just a matter of converting those into a MERGE statement to do the update, and an insert statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the detailed explanation. I up-voted ...  did't accept - cause at the end - I followed AlexPoole's advise and incorporated all computations inside the cursor. Thanks again!

Comment: Depending on how big the mytable is, you may find it more performant to do the two separate statements rather than looping through the cursor.

Comment: Ok, so I tried your approach (had to create a temporary table with all needed intermediate computations first - as the real world problem is more complicated the the one that I presented above). The final result,though,  is indeed a lot faster - so answer - accepted ;-)